# How to populate fields in tab control when entering firstname in text search box; VBA7?

Tags: ms-access-2016, vba7, ms-access-forms

So,I have btnSearch when click it will populate myTabControl23. I been trying to search by first name and to populate the tab control but it cant.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
    SearchAndPopulate
End Sub

Private Sub SearchAndPopulate()
        Dim searchCriteria As String
        searchCriteria = Me.txtSearch.Value  
    
        ' Your query to retrieve data based on search criteria
        Dim strSQL As String
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblPersonal " & _
                 "WHERE PersonnelID = " & searchCriteria & ";"
    
        ' Execute the query
        Me.RecordSource = strSQL
    
        ' Refresh the form to display the updated records
        Me.Refresh
        
        Debug.Print "SQL Query: " & strSQL
    End Sub
```

I have tried some tutorial to add FirstName as search but I got errors. I then revert back to search by ID.

> Note the form row source control is wired to tblPersonal.

Please can someone help me on how to search by firstname and on selection it populates the tab control.

> Below is my tab control image;

[image: Tab Control Image]